# Does HTML support alternative text for special characters (e.g., accented characters)?

Tags: html, html-entities

I envision HTML support that might look like this:

<span alt="Antonin Dvorak">Anton&iacute;n Dvo&#345;&aacute;k</span>

where if a browser could not render any of the special characters, it could fall back to the plain-ASCII "alt" text.  Another benefit could be that searching for "cafe" would match "café" (which my browsers don't, at least not at present).

Is there any way to achieve something like this, or am I just being paranoid about a non-existent problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Any examples of where special characters fail? What user agent these days cannot handle Unicode characters? If you use UTF-8 encoding I'd not worry about characters not rendering.

Comment: This question wasn't prompted by an example of failure, just paranoia.  Sounds like UTF-8 and European letters are pretty well supported these days, so I should just not worry.  Thanks.

Comment: @SuanYong, it’s sane to worry about such things. For example, with Google web fonts, one of the common problems is that characters like “ř” don’t work—either because they are not available in the chosen font, or “Latin Extended” was not included when selecting the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such markup in HTML. What comes closest is the `title` attribute, which is usually shown as a tooltip on mouseover (and spoken by speech synthesizers in some situations). But it’s a dull weapon, a feature with poor implementations; if you want something like that, use a CSS tooltip instead. And it’s not really an alternative but “advisory title”.

The best you can do is to make a reasonable effort in ensuring that the characters you use will be properly displayed thanks to the use of suitable fonts. This isn’t usually a problem with Czech letters for example, since they are normally present in fonts that web pages typically use, like Arial, Verdana, Georgia. But it could be a problem if you use a downloadable font, or if you use characters with more limited support. The general idea is to use a `font-family` list that contains only fonts that have all the characters used on the page, and to use such a list that almost all computers have at least one of the font families. More on this: [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Comment: True, one has to use a font with good support for your target locale. And ensure you encode the text in an appropriate character encoding. Using UTF-8 is something I'd recommend everyone to do - and make sure to use it consistently across the project.